# Navigate back to the main screen without showing a back button in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, navigationbar

I am creating an Ionic application. After the user uploads an image, I want to send them back to the main screen and refresh the data that is shown.

Whenever I use `$state.go("app.home")` or `location.href = "#/app/home"`, a Back button is shown to the user. I do not want this behavior because the user is now back on the main screen and there should not be any back button in the nav-bar.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for my problem:

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
  disableBack: true
});

$state.go("app.home");
```